# I just couldn't build this iwlwifi core source. Others could

Tags: 16.04, compiling, make, iwlwifi, makefile

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release
So I'm trying to get wireless working on my laptop with Ubuntu 16.04. I figure I need to build the package as the wiki instruct; install iwlwifi LinuxCore14. But the 'make' always return several errors that seem to be related to the source rather than the environment. Weird thing is, many other people successfully compiled the same source. I've got build-essential installed. Is there something else im missing? Here is an error example :

```
error: passing argument 6 of ‘dev_coredumpm’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
         GFP_KERNEL, iwl_mvm_read_coredump, iwl_mvm_free_coredump);
```

Here is the result for `rfkill list; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

```
1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth [8086:3166] (rev 99)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth [8086:4210]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
--
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:3884]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Result of `dmidecode | grep -i lenovo`  :

```
Vendor: LENOVO
Manufacturer: LENOVO
Version: Lenovo Y520-15IKBN
SKU Number: LENOVO_MT_80WK_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo Y520-15IKBN
Manufacturer: LENOVO
Manufacturer: LENOVO
Version: Lenovo Y520-15IKBN
```

Comment: try core 24 as the source for 14 might be too old

Comment: @Jeremy31 Im on intel ac3165. Core14 is the last one to support it.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the error messages from `make` into your question?

Comment: Also edit to include results for `rfkill list; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: `rfkill` shows that your wireless is hard blocked; in other words, the switch or key combination is set to disable wireless. Building another driver can't move a physical switch. What model of Lenovo is this?

Comment: @chili552 so this have nothing to do with the driver?

Comment: Correct. It has to do with the switch or key combination entirely. The driver and most likely, the firmware, are in place and ready to go.

Comment: Edit to include results for `sudo dmidecode | grep -i lenovo`

Comment: Doesn't the key combination `Fn`+`F7` enable wireless?

Comment: @chili555 no. It toggle airplane mode

Comment: Correct! However, doesn't airplane mode do just that? Turn the wireless radio on or off?

Comment: @chili555 it seem to change the soft block state.

Comment: What about the phy0. It is unblocked. Can I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try an experiment. From the terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

If this enables wireless, we can blacklist the module in order to make it permanent.

Since we now know that this methods enabled your wireless, let's make it permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist ideapad-laptop"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Comment: You're the best. The first command fixed it. Many thanks:)

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for [LinuxCore14](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git/log/?h=release/LinuxCore14) is close to 2 years old and that is why it wouldn't compile in Ubuntu 16.04. [LinuxCore24](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git/log/?h=release%2FLinuxCore24) has source code that was patched a couple weeks ago and would have compiled as I just tested it