# SOLVED - Lenovo ideapad-100 17.10 lost wifi and battery support

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, lenovo, battery

after an update I rebooted only to find out that I lost some kernel module, wl is no longer there (meaning I no longer have wifi) also my battery is acting up because acpi no longer find my battery... this is bad because I can no longer shutdown properly (since acpi think my laptop is now a desktop...) 
I also have random freeze when idle...

that said I use a minimal install with wicd for network so resolv.conf is not applicable here.

mprobe show that the wl module is not installed  (it was before the update)

acpi report that it cannot run with (power_supply) again a missing kernel module ?

booting in an older kernel is irrelevant since there is no modules installed (yay)

my question is how do I install those module back ?

note: I am not using the original wifi card. I am using a Centrino N-6235.

edit: here is the output for

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iw
[   27.698508] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: found PCI INT A -> IRQ 6
[   27.973964] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1op_modeiwldvm
[   28.364123] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   28.364125] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   28.364127] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled   
[   28.364129] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6235 AGN, REV=0xB0
[   28.377155] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: reporting RF_KILL (radio disabled)
[   28.440126] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[   28.581807] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   31.410345] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
```

this is for the command rfkill list all

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Edit 2:
 I completely forgot that I tried to fix the freeze issue by blocking acpi ...  at the time it did noting, that kernel update must have correctly read the config file and actually blocked apci removing access to the battery info and blocking the wifi card for some odd reason, apparently it hard block the card.

I used the cstate bug fix and no more freezing issue. [Handling questions about the Bay Trail c-state bug](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16794/handling-questions-about-the-bay-trail-c-state-bug)
I probably should have read that before trying to fix the problem in a random way.

Comment: "I am not using the original wifi card. I am using a Centrino N-6235." The driver for this is not `wl`; it is `iwlwifi`. Please edit your question to show the output of the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` and also: `rfkill list all`.

Comment: regarding the battery situation it seems to be the same as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1179010

Comment: I can't answer the battery issue, but the wireless is likely this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/895617/i-just-couldnt-build-this-iwlwifi-core-source-others-could/895659#895659

Comment: still no wifi the laptop does not have a physical switch  ... wifi is working in windows so ireally have no clue as to what is going on

Comment: F7 is Airplane Mode. That's the same thing. Press it and check again: `rfkill list all`

Comment: Fn+F7 did it ... also fixed the apci battery issue .... trying to fix the cstate bug, I disabled acpi ... it was working but the update must have changed someting because I have forgotten to remove the no-acpi line in my grub config. after a compleate reboot it all works like charm

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.